# On iMac, using external monitor only intermittently

Tags: display, imac

I have an external monitor hooked up to my iMac. I only use it when I'm coding, so mostly it's off. But some windows can get lost over there, because as far as my iMac knows, it's still in use. What's the best way to deactivate it?

- Unplug it from the back of the iMac until I want to use it again
  (drag)
- Mirror the displays when not using, so nothing will get lost over there (I think this makes my primary monitor appear look weird, since my external monitor is portrait and my main monitor is landscape.)
- Some other way?

Comment: Can you turn off the power?  Not just put it in standby, but fully power it off?

Comment: @Allan I don't know how. I could put a switch on the AC outlet maybe

Comment: Before looking at something like that, just unplug and see if that solves the issue.